# Can you use a mailto link in HTML to send a pre-filled, pre-styled email?

Tags: html, css, ios, email, mailto

I know how to send a pre-filled email using a mailto link as seen below:

```
<a class="helloBtn" href="mailto:test@testmail.co.uk?&subject=Hello%20there!&body=Good%20Morning,%0d%0dHow%20are%20you%20today?">Say Hello!</a>
```

But when you click the button on an apple mobile device, the apple mail app doesn't format the text correctly. I believe this is because it sees the text as plain text. So instead of appearing like this:

"Body: Good Morning,

How are you today?"

**It appears like this:**

"Body: Good Morning, How are you today?"

I.E - It ignores the new line formatting etc.

After some research, one way around this is to add some styling the the email so it sees it as HTML rather than plain text. But can you do this via a mailto link?

I hope this makes sense, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You tried with `%0d` which makes sense for MacOS. But could you try to use also line feed, i.e. `%0a`. Just to be sure ;)

Comment: I just tried your HTML snippet on my MacOS and it worked as you expected. I got three lines in my Mail app on Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will try that. I wasn't very clear in my question but I am only talking about the mail app on mobile devices. Sorry about that I will edit the question!